# How to match and iterate on a string after another string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
"abc-12\nxyz-17\nabc-18\npqr-13\n"
```

I want to match the number after each string and sum them all up. For example, I want to sum `12` and `18` for `abc`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "abc-12\nxyz-17\nabc-18\npqr-13\n"

s.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,e| id, n = e.split('-'); h[id] += n.to_i; h }
=> {"abc"=>30, "xyz"=>17, "pqr"=>13}
```

Comment: Is there a Ruby Idiom to convert the generated hash to two arrays. I want to get ["abc", "xyz", "pqr"] and [30, 17, 13]. I ended up writing a method for this.

Comment: @navgeet - `Hash` has methods named `keys` and `values`. Those give you the arrays you need respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
"abc-12\nxyz-17\nabc-18\npqr-13\n".split("\n").inject(0) do |sum, line|
  sum += line[/[\w]+(\d)+/].to_i
end
```